# When trying to print from string getting error: Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that receives a format normally seen in a `printf` call and a string of integers separated by an inconsistent amount of spaces. It prints the format how it would've been printed from `printf` with the correct representation of the integers.
I first tried to create the `extractNums` function that returns an array of all the integers from the second string sent to the `printFormattedIntegers` function.
But later in `printFormattedIntegers` I get a `Exception: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT` error when I simply try to print the first element of the format string. I found that if I comment out the `extractNums` function call, I get no error and it works.
I'm not sure why the `extractNums` call interrupts the rest of the program, any ideas?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define I 1
#define V 5
#define X 10
#define L 50
#define C 100
#define D 500
#define M 1000

void printFormattedIntegers(char* format, char numbers[]);
char converter(char c, int num);
int charToInt(char* str);
int* extendArr(int* arr, int currSize);
int* extractNums(char* nums);
void printDecAsBin(int num);
void printDEC(int num);
void printHEX(int num);
void printOCT(int num);
void printBIN(int num);
void printROM(int num);

void main()
{
    char format[100];
    char numbers[100];
    printFormattedIntegers("Dec: %d Hex: %x Roman: %r", " 123  10 9");
}


void printFormattedIntegers(char* format, char* numbers)
{
   int formatInd = 0, numsInd = 0;
   int* numsArr = extractNums(numbers);
   while (format[formatInd] != '\0')
   {
       if (format[formatInd] != '%')
           printf("%c",format[formatInd]);
       else
       {
           converter(format[formatInd+1], numsArr[numsInd]);
           numsInd++;
       }
       formatInd++;
   }
}

char converter(char c, int num)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'd':
            printDEC(num);
            break;
        case 'x':
            printHEX(num);
            break;
        case 'o':
            printOCT(num);
            break;
        case 'b':
            printBIN(num);
            break;
        case 'r':
            printROM(num);
            break;
        case '\0':
            printf("%%");
            break;
        default:
            printf("%%%c",c);
            break;
    }
}

int charToInt(char* str)
{
    int mult = 1;
    int re = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);
    for(int i = len -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        re = re + ((int)str[i] -48)*mult;
        mult = mult*10;
    }
    return re;
}

int* extendArr(int* arr, int currSize)
{
    int* newArr;
    int i;
    newArr = (int*)malloc((currSize+1) * sizeof(int));
    if (newArr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i=0;i<currSize;i++)
        newArr[i] = arr[i];
    free(arr);
    return newArr;
}

int* extractNums(char* nums)
{
    char *copiedStr, *token;
    int *newArr=NULL,counter = 0, intChar;
    char sep[] = " ";
    strcpy(copiedStr,nums);
    token = strtok(copiedStr,sep);
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        intChar = charToInt(token);
        newArr = extendArr(newArr,counter);
        newArr[counter] = intChar;
        counter++;
        token = strtok(NULL,sep);
    }
}

void printDecAsBin(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
        printf("0");
    else if (num == 1)
        printf("1");
    else
    {
        printDecAsBin(num / 2);
        printf("%d", num % 2);
    }
}
void printDEC(int num)
{
    printf("%d", num);
}
void printHEX(int num)
{
    printf("%x", num);
}
void printOCT(int num)
{
    printf("%o", num);
}
void printBIN(int num)
{
    printDecAsBin(num);
}
void printROM(int num)
{
    while (num >= M)
    {
        num -= M;
        printf("M");
    }
    if (num >= M - C)
    {
        printf("CM");
        num -= (M - C);
    }
    else if (num >= D)
    {
        printf("D");
        num -= D;
    }
    while (num >= C)
    {
        num -= C;
        printf("C");
    }
    if (num >= C - X)
    {
        printf("XC");
        num -= (C - X);
    }
    else if (num >= L)
    {
        printf("L");
        num -= L;
    }
    while (num >= X)
    {
        num -= X;
        printf("X");
    }
    if (num >= X - I)
    {
        printf("IX");
        num -= (X - I);
    }
    else if (num >= V)
    {
        printf("V");
        num -= V;
    }
    while (num > 0)
    {
        num -= I;
        printf("I");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing to unallocated memory. That invokes Undefined Behaviour and from that point anything can happen at any moment:

```
int* extractNums(char* nums)
{
    char *copiedStr, *token;             // copiedStr is an initialized pointer here
    int *newArr=NULL,counter = 0, intChar;
    char sep[] = " ";
    strcpy(copiedStr,nums);              // use of the initialized pointer: UB!
```

Comment: And after you may free a memory not allocated (in extendArr : free(are) the first time when newArr is NULL)

Comment: This solved my initial problem but another popped up. It is what @PtitXav mentioned, I'm not sure what to pass to the  extendArr function.

Comment: Before freeing arr, test if it is not NULL.